# Express each of the standard basis vectors as linear combination of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given the vectors $\alpha_1=(1,0,-1)$, $\alpha_2=(1,2,1)$, $\alpha_3=(0,-3,2)$, express each of the standard basis vectors as linear combination of $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\alpha_3$.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Do you know what the question is asking?

Comment: i dont know how to express  e1,e2,e3 as combination of the given vectors

Comment: I see that this user doesn't like to accept answers and generally doesn't provide any of his own work toward a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Construct a matrix with those vectors as columns, and try to convert your question into the solution of a matrix equation.

Letting the $\alpha_i$ be written as column vectors, use the fact that $$\lambda_1\alpha_1+\lambda_2\alpha_2+\lambda_3\alpha_3=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & -3 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve $Ax=b$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0\\
0&2&-3\\
-1&1&2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 &y_1&z_1\\
x_2&y_2&z_2\\
x_3&y_2&z_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$x=A^{-1}b$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 &y_1&z_1\\
x_2&y_2&z_2\\
x_3&y_2&z_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
.7&-.2&-.3\\
.3&.2&.3\\
.2&-.2&.2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: That equation doesn't make sense. The rhs should be a vector, or you should change the second column vector to a matrix. Essentially the answer I've given.